# Export HTML string to Excel file in ASP.Net using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, xls

I have this table in database `MySql version 8.0.17` which contains HTML code on field `contents`

```html
<p><h3><span style=color:#0000ff;><strong>test</strong></span></h3></p>
<h4><strong>- test1</strong></h4>
<h4><strong>- test2</strong></h4>
```

I am not DB admin so I can only read from this table which i cannot modify..

when exporting this table in excel format on the xls file all HTML tags are found

[image]

How to do resolve this?

Thanks in advance for any help.

My code below

```cs
private void MTxlssp()
{
    MySqlCommand cmd =
        new MySqlCommand("SP");

    DataTable dt = GetData(cmd);
    GridView GridView1 = new GridView
    {
        AllowPaging = false,
        DataSource = dt
    };

    GridView1.DataBind();

    Thread.Sleep(3000);
    Response.Clear();
    Response.Buffer = true;

    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", attachment;filename=\"test.xls\"");

    Response.ContentEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
    Response.Charset = "";
    Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";

    HttpCookie cookie2 = new HttpCookie("ExcelDownloadFlag")
    {
        Value = "Flag",
        Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1)
    };
    Response.AppendCookie(cookie2);

    using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter())
    {
        HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);

        GridView1.HeaderRow.BackColor = Color.White;

        foreach (TableCell cell in GridView1.HeaderRow.Cells)
        {
            cell.BackColor = GridView1.HeaderStyle.BackColor;
        }
        foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
        {
            row.BackColor = Color.White;
            foreach (TableCell cell in row.Cells)
            {
                if (row.RowIndex % 2 == 0)
                {
                    cell.BackColor = GridView1.AlternatingRowStyle.BackColor;
                }
                else
                {
                    cell.BackColor = GridView1.RowStyle.BackColor;
                }
                cell.CssClass = "textmode";
            }
        }

        GridView1.RenderControl(hw);
        string style = @"<style> .textmode { } </style>";
        Response.Write(style);
        Response.Output.Write(sw.ToString());
        Response.Flush();
        Response.End();
    }
}
```

Comment: Give a clear explanation: what result excel file do you want to get from the html you provided?

Comment: @IvanKhorin Only text without tag html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If its just the display text you need then maybe the library Nuglify will help you.  It supports text extraction from HTML:

```
var html = @"<p><h3><span style=color:#0000ff;><strong>test</strong></span></h3></p>
<h4><strong>- test1</strong></h4>
<h4><strong>- test2</strong></h4>";

var result = Uglify.HtmlToText(html);

Console.WriteLine(result.Code);
```

You can download it from here: https://github.com/trullock/NUglify or get it from Nuget.

I have just run it on your html sample and it produces:

```
 test - test1 - test2
```

I am assuming thats what you want based on your comment to @Ivan Khorin